# HashMap of HashMap of Generic Type serialization in Java

Tags: java, generics, serialization, hashmap, serializable

Fixed, per Engineer Dollery's answer, solution at bottom.

The goal is to serialize the network field of class Network. Sorry for the naming.

I had this, which compiled, and serialized properly.

```
public class Network {
    private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Number>> network;
    ...
    public void load(String networkFile) throws Exception{
        network = (HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Number>>)Utility.deserialize(Utility.load(networkFile));
    }

    public void save(String networkFile) throws Exception{
        Utility.save(networkFile, Utility.serialize(network));
    }
}

class Number implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

I changed it to this generic version, which compiles, but no longer serializes. I need someway to specify that HashMap of T and Number is serializable.

```
public class Network<T extends Serializable> {
    private HashMap<T, HashMap<T, Number>> network;
    ...

    public void load(String networkFile) throws Exception{
        network = (HashMap<T, HashMap<T, Number>>)Utility.deserialize(Utility.load(networkFile));
    }

    public void save(String networkFile) throws Exception{
        Utility.save(networkFile, Utility.serialize(network));
    }
}

class Number implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

And this is the code for serialization

```
package Bullib;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Utility{

    public static Pattern phrasePattern = Pattern.compile("[^;:!.?]+");
    public static Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile("['A-Za-z]+");

    public static Object deserialize(byte[] serialized) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(serialized);
        ObjectInputStream si = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
        return si.readObject();
    }

    public static byte[] serialize(Object target) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream so = new ObjectOutputStream(bo);
        so.writeObject(target);
        so.flush();
        return bo.toByteArray();
    }

    public static byte[] load(String filename)  throws Exception {
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(new File(filename), "r");
        byte[] b = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        file.read(b);
        file.close();
        return b;
    }

    public static void save(String filename, byte[] value) throws Exception {
        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(new File(filename), "rw");
        file.write(value);
        file.close();
    }

    public static Collection<String> executeRegex(Pattern pattern, String text){
        LinkedList<String> matches = new LinkedList<String>();
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (m.find()) {
            matches.add(m.group(0));
        }
        return matches;
    }
}
```

This is the error I get back when trying to serialize with `T` as either `String` or `Double`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: Bullib.Network.Netw
ork
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at Bullib.Utility.serialize(Utility.java:21)
        at Bullib.Network.Network.save(Network.java:88)
        at Engine.save(Engine.java:63)
        at Engine.main(Engine.java:88)
```

Per requests, an example test and error. As you can see, it produces the same exception as above. I've updated the test to show that it passes if nothing is added to the map, and fails otherwise.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Network<String> stringtest = new Network<String>("","","");
    stringtest.save("testempty");
    stringtest.load("testempty");
    System.out.println("passed empty");
    stringtest.placeAndMove("fill",0.0);
    stringtest.save("testfilled");
    stringtest.load("testfilled");
    System.out.println("passed filled");
}

java: Bullib/Network/Network
passed empty
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: Bullib.Network.Netw
ork
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at Bullib.Utility.serialize(Utility.java:21)
        at Bullib.Network.Network.save(Network.java:88)
        at Bullib.Network.Network.main(Network.java:108)
```

The solution is to change

```
public class Network<T extends Serializable> {
    private HashMap<T, HashMap<T, Number>> network;
    ...

    public void load(String networkFile) throws Exception{
        network = (HashMap<T, HashMap<T, Number>>)Utility.deserialize(Utility.load(networkFile));
    }

    public void save(String networkFile) throws Exception{
        Utility.save(networkFile, Utility.serialize(network));
    }
}

class Number implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

to

```
public class Network<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
    private HashMap<T, HashMap<T, Number>> network;
    ...

    public void load(String networkFile) throws Exception{
        network = (HashMap<T, HashMap<T, Number>>)Utility.deserialize(Utility.load(networkFile));
    }

    public void save(String networkFile) throws Exception{
        Utility.save(networkFile, Utility.serialize(network));
    }
}

class Number implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You cut out the most important line of the error...

Comment: Is the `Network` class itself serializable? Also, you didn't copy the topmost line of the stack trace.

Comment: Apologies, let me clarify all this stuff

Comment: `NotSerializableException` tells you what non-serializable class is trying to be serialized.  In your error message, it tells you that `Bullib.Network.Network` is the non-serializable class causing the exception, meaning that the issue here appears to be your `Network` class itself, not the hashmap contained within it.  Your `Network` class needs to implement `Serializable`.

Comment: From what I can see, nothing is wrong. The `NotSerializableException` is thrown when there is an object at runtime that is not serializable. What are you using instead of the `String` now? Try `String`, it will work. And then make sure that whatever it is you're stuffing in there does _not_ have an unserializable field. As always, debugging the process step-by-step would probably reveal the issue to you.

Comment: It is Network.network I am trying to serialize. It's a hashmap of key T and value hashmap of key T and value Number. Number extends serializable and T is constrained to serializable

Comment: Well, then it's simple, show us the serializing code.

Comment: @user1982116 Your error message seems to disagree with your claims, as it indicates that your `Network` class isn't serializable.  According to the code in your question, *it isn't*.  Could you please update the code in the question to accurately reflect the code causing the error?

Comment: You can't store an instance variable without saving the object. And object type should implement Serializable.

Comment: Your class Network should implement Serializable, inorder to participate in Serialization process.

Comment: I've [recreated your code](http://pastebin.com/55ALmzh4), and it runs without exception.  The issue, as mentioned earlier, is that you are trying to serialize an instance of an unserializable class, `Network`.

Comment: 'network' is one of the instance variables and Object is of type 'Network'.

Comment: You need to implement Serializable right ? Even when you don't use generics.

Comment: You are writing what is called non-canonical code. This makes it hard to answer questions because it's difficult to read. The convention is to use lower case names for packages. The code and the error will be easier to read for everyone else if you follow this convention.

Comment: Sorry, i'll have to go through and edit that. I've been through so many different languages, keeping it canonical gets confusing.

Comment: My answer below still stands. Try it. Then you may have another question - how to serialize only specific fields, which is covered in the comments below my answer.

Comment: I've updated the post to show all calls used for serialization. Is your answer still correct? I'm not serializing the Network class, only the network field, so I can't see why it would be necessary to declare the Network class Serializable. Is this incorrect?

Comment: I can't upvote, but I just confirmed that your answer suggesting change 
`public class Network`
to
`public class Network implements Serializable`
worked properly.

Comment: I know it works, but I can't see why you have the problem (partially because your code is a little unusual -- you should avoid statics and typically loading/saving objects isn't the responsibility of the object itself but of a separate repository). I'm loading your code into IntelliJ to see what the real problem is.

Comment: Could you explain why serializing a field of a class requires the class to be serializable?

Comment: Ok, I've just run your code and the problem isn't that Network isn't serializable. I don't really know what the real problem is because the code you've posted doesn't run right (i get null pointers, and there are missing methods and constructors). However, I have filled in the blanks and I don't get any error, let alone the one you have posted above. The code above tries to save before load, this means that the network hashmap isn't initialized before it's accessed, which throws a null-pointer. Fix this and it runs ok.

Comment: Sorry, I had omitted Network's constructor. In my code, it is initialized properly, and values are successfully added to the network hashmap.
Does your code still work if you do not implement Serializable on Network, initialize the network hashmap, and add a single value to the network hashmap, then attempt to serialize?

This scenario is the one described in my test case.

Comment: Where do you set the path?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public class Network implements Serializable
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typo -- that's what I get for coding in an edit box. the network field is fully serializable already, the error message refers to the Network class, not the network field. I'm assuming that Bullib.Network.Network is package.package.class. It would be nice if you'd remove the -1 you gave this answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Aman You can override readObject and writeObject to work with only one field, rather than the whole class, if you really wanted that. Or, you could mark all the other fields as transitive.

Comment: You mean 'transient'. iPad strikes again?

Comment: Sorry, mental block rather than spell checker. I've just answered a question on transitive dependencies and that popped into my head in place of transient! Thanks.